# QT Designer QTableWidget как учитывать ширину колонок по самому заголовку и по ширине содержимого ячеек

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qtablewidget

[image: QTableWidget]

*QT Designer* `QTableWidget` - как учитывать ширину колонок по самому заголовку и по ширине содержимого ячеек,
чтобы максимально все информация влезала и лишнего не было.

Ширину по содержимому ячеек ранее сделал так:

```
self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

> QHeaderView *QTableView::`horizontalHeader()` const
>
> Возвращает горизонтальный заголовок табличного представления.
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget-members.html

> void QHeaderView::`setSectionResizeMode`(QHeaderView::ResizeMode mode)
>
> Устанавливает ограничения на то, как размер заголовка может быть изменен до тех,
> которые описаны в данном режиме.
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode

> `QHeaderView::ResizeToContents`
>
> QHeaderView автоматически изменит размер раздела до оптимального размера
> в зависимости от содержимого всего столбца или строки.
> Размер не может быть изменен пользователем или программно. 
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))
        self.myarray = [
            [1, 2, 3, 4], 
            [1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1], 
            [1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2], 
            [1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 4.3]
        ]
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 
    
        line = len(self.myarray)
        column = len(self.myarray[0])
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(line)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(column)
        row_labels = ['A', '222', 'Hello World']
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(row_labels) 

        for c, row in enumerate(self.myarray):
            for r, e in enumerate(row):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(e))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, item)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(0)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Windows")
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как QHeaderView показать в коде или обьявить в программе (просто вставив его ругается pycharm типо  unreresolved reference )  ? В документации фиг поймеш

Comment: @almaz я не понимаю, что вы и куда вставляете? Вы пробовали мой пример? Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.